# How to divide the image into top and bottom when having the indices of line

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to divide the image into two sections (top and bottom) after drawing a line as shown in the figure,

[image]

I some how got the indices of the red line drew by three points (A,B,C).
How can I now seperate this based on indices.

Thanks,
Gopi

Edit:

I got the answer by this code:

```
top_img = zeros(size(img));
for cols = all_idxs(1,:)
    top_img(1:all_idxs(2,find(all_idxs(1,:)==cols,1,'first')),cols) = ,...
        img(1:all_idxs(2,find(all_idxs(1,:)==cols,1,'first')),cols);
end
bottom_img = img - top_img;
figure,
subplot(121),imshow(top_img,[]);
subplot(122),imshow(bottom_img,[]);
```

[image]

If there is cleaner code to either draw that line as fig1 or fig2. Please let me know.

Comment: Would you please try to explain better what you would like to improve in the current solution? I cannot understand what you're asking.